# VBA code to compare text within text in different rows and if part of text matches add values to a single row then delete the other row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little experience in VBA but I'm trying to get this done.
I have a list of about 100 employees in a call center and have a report with the times they work. Some of them work different functions and they are only differentiated by a function id included within their name, eg:

```
WilliamsMLEA_Mariana    08:22:24    8.37    01:45:55    1.77    FT  1.5 1.77    7.5 6.87    6.61    88.1%
WilliamsMPRE_Mariana    00:37:15    0.62    00:00:01    0.00    FT  1.5 0.00    7.5 -0.88   0.62    8.3%
```

All names are on column A and diferent values on columns B, C, D, etc.
I need to to find a way to compare the different rows and see if the name matches and if so add values from columns B, C, D, etc to a single row and delete the others so I have the total sum of both rows.
Please note that the worksheet contains about 100 rows with names and values.
In other words I need to consolidate the values of the row with MLEA string into the row with MPRE string then delete the MLEA row.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think it would help if you copy pasted some actual samples from the different sheets (you can then obscure the data if you like). Also, what happens if there are two John Smith's doing the same function?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pivot table would do what you want.

Click in your data

Choose insert / pivot table

Select what you want to see through the drag and drop interface

Enjoy the output.